# Wordpress site broken, editor not working properly or at all

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

im working on adding and modifying the content of a website, but im having multiple issues with the very basic functioning of the editor. Please keep in mind i didnt build this site myself, so i might not be aware of many things that may be obvious to you.

If left unmodified, to the user, the site shows no issues whastoever, it is I as the administrator who experiencies all these issues.

I will describe/ show the issue and give a list of the things i have tried already.

1. While looking at Cpanel's PHP admin app, and the htaccess file, i see the php version is 7.4. However, while using wordpress, the site health status tool warns me that im using php version 7.1.33
2. Im not getting the admin bar when looking at the website, it just shows a white bar with nothing else.

3.If i go to the backend editor and try to customize the template im using (called Jupiter 5) i get very few options in the side bar, it doesnt show things like header options for example. And i have no floating editor options on the site itself, i get no tools, nothing.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDJnH.png)

4. When i go inside wordpress to "pages" and try to edit a page, the editor box shows the content with the code included or shows nothing while using the "visual composer" mode. [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8kpP.jpg)
5. When i try changing the template, the content appears like this.  [A huge mess, though some editor controls show up in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u64qL.png)

6.I tried using plugin detective but when i launch it, and it asks for my credentials, i hit login yet it does nothing.

7. I  tried disabling all plugins, only header and bottom show up kinda normally, the body becomes text with code like the image of point 5. I still dont get the admin bar on site.
8. If  I, after disabling all plugins go to pages, then select any page and click "edit", the adress of the site shows im on the edit page, but the page itself is completely blank, i dont even get the wordpress bar at the left.
9. If I disable all plugins, then activate only a plugin called WPBakery, the body of the site stops showing text with code and actually shows most visual elements, no edit options though, except for a small text at the bottom. A weird thing about this plugin is that despite of its name, when activated, it shows up as "Visual Composer" instead of WPBakery.

So far, besides disabling plugins and testing, i have only tried Updating Wordpress, the only thing that changes is that the admin bar finally shows, but the "customization" mode remains exactly the same, useless.

Classic editor is already installed btw.

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow, Andreas! It looks like you are asking many questions in a single post. Please split your problem into specific questions (and different posts) so you can get better help.

Comment: I posted my troubleshooting, i don't even know what's the cause of the issues. Posting questions in separate posts would lead to wrong answers as they are probably related problems

Comment: This would be like having multiple symptoms and making different posts for each one of them, that's often not the best way to diagnose a disease